# Filter for Flask-Restless doesn't filter results

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

I am trying to use requests to send a filter query to Flask-Restless.  The results are not filtered.  How do I correctly write a filter?

```
import requests
import json
q = {'filters': [{'task': 'build an API', 'task': 'profit'}]}
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/toworks', params={'q': json.dumps(q)})
```

I expect the results to only contain the first and third items, but the second one is present as well.

```
{
    "towork1": {
        "task": "build an API"
    }, 
    "towork2": {
        "task": "?????"
    }, 
    "towork3": {
        "task": "profit!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you've used for the filter is completely wrong.  There should be a list of filters, each one being a dict with `name`, `op`, and `value` keys.  Since you want to search within the value of a task, use the `like` op with wildcards (`%`) before and after the value you're filtering on.  You'll also need to use an `or` since the two filters are mutually exclusive.

```
q = {'filters': [{'or': [
    {'name': 'task', 'op': 'like', 'val': '%build%'},
    {'name': 'task', 'op': 'like', 'val': '%profit%'}
]}]}
```